# iOS-Charts: Line format in legend not complete

Tags: ios-charts

When I format a line for a line chart f.e.

```
lineData = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals: data label: @"xy"];
[lineData setColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.f green: 0.2f blue: 0.2f alpha: 0.5f]];
lineData.lineWidth = 6.f;
lineData.lineDashLengths = @[@5.f, @2.5f];
```

the line will be represented in the legend with only the color. The line width and dashing do not appear in the legend.

Can I change line formatting in the legend? Am I missing something?

Comment: seems legend does not use lineDashLengths? Have you checked legend code

Comment: @Wingzero: You'r right. In legend code lineWidth and lineDashLengths are not used (iOS-Charts version 2.2.4). I now changed legend code to use these parameters for lineCharts (in files Components/ChartLegend.swift, Renderers/ChartLegendRenderer.swift, Utils/ChartUtils.swift) and sent my improvements to Daniel Gindi. Perhaps he will include them in future versions of iOS-Charts.